# AngularJS Ressource with ChartAngular (Morris.JS Directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, morris.js

I'm using this AngularJS directive for Morris-Charts: https://github.com/BilalBudhani/ChartAngular

I can use this directive from my html-page like this:

```
<donutchart id="TicketStatistik" data-options="chart_options"></donutchart>
```

I have a AngularJS Resource defined like this:

```
   .factory('barChartData', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('./api/chart',
            { },
            { 'query': { method: 'GET' } }
        );
    }
])
```

This is the AngularJS Controller:

```
.controller('DonutChartCtrl', function ($scope) {     
   $scope.chart_options = {
        data: [
            { label: "Download Sales", value: 12 },
            { label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30 },
            { label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20 }
        ]
    };
})
```

How can I manage, that I can query my resource `barChartData` for the datasource of my `DonutChartCtrl`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey I wrote a directive for making morris charts with angular: https://github.com/jasonshark/ng-morris/blob/master/src/ngMorris.js It's also available via bower: `bower install ngmorris --save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the factory dependency in the controller. Like:

`.controller('DonutChartCtrl', function ($scope, barChartData)`

And then you can use the functions inside the controller.
e.g.:

```
 $scope.chart_list = barChartData.query();
```